# Python Function Exception Error

Tags: python, function, indentation

I've writen a code you'll find below but it doesn't work. I get an indentation error. This is the message I've received from cmd.

[image]

Can you tell me where I've done the mistake?

```
loan = input("indiquer le montant de l'emprunt")
loan = float(loan)
duree = input("indiquer la durée de l'emprunt en mois")
duree = int(duree)
principal = loan / duree
tauxinteret = input("mettre le taux d'intéret")
tauxinteret = float(tauxinteret)
interets = principal * tauxinteret
assurance = input("indiquer le montant des assurances")
assurance = float(assurance)
mensualite = principal + interets + assurance
return mensualite
print("Mr l'esclave, la mensualité à payer s'élève à {} dirhams". format (mensualite)") 

calcul_mensualite(mensualite)
```

Comment: did you define a function in the first two lines that are not in the code?

Comment: seems like this is part of a function and you haven't indented it by 4 spaces

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at defining functions in Python (seems like you tried to do that) - after `def` you need to indent next lines:

```
def my_function():
    print("Hello from a function")

my_function()
```

And here's the link to the basics:

[functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have left out the define statement of the method. You will again get an indentation error because you have included a return statement outside of a method. The following code should work fine after removing the return statement.

```
loan = input("indiquer le montant de l'emprunt")
loan = float(loan)
duree = input("indiquer la durée de l'emprunt en mois")
duree = int(duree)
principal = loan / duree
tauxinteret = input("mettre le taux d'intéret")
tauxinteret = float(tauxinteret)
interets = principal * tauxinteret
assurance = input("indiquer le montant des assurances")
assurance = float(assurance)
mensualite = principal + interets + assurance
print("Mr l'esclave, la mensualité à payer s'élève à {} dirhams". format (mensualite)")
```

Comment: sorry there is one missing line in my code:                                                             def calcul_mensualite (loan, principal, duree,tauxinteret, interets, assurance, mensualite):

Comment: Even with defining function line. indentation error still exist

Comment: In that case you need to add an indentation to every line after that statement except the last line of your code which calls the function.

Comment: add four spaces(preferably) before every statement after the define line except the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for you all. there is one missing line in my code:

def calcul_mensualite (loan, principal, duree,tauxinteret, interets, assurance, mensualite):